# execute a rule that the wildcard is obtained via the params in the rule

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

I have a rule that contains a wildcard that is taken from the params (decided by a function). Is it possible to run this single rule by calling it by name, e.g., snakemake a

```
rule a:
    input: file1, file2
    output: directory(1), directory("2/{domain}.txt")
    params:
        domain_cat = lambda wc, input: pd.read_csv(input[1], index_col=0).loc[wc.domain, "cat"]
    shell:
        """
        example.py {input} {output} {params.domain_cat}"
        """
```

Answer (score 1):

No. If a rule contains a wildcard, you can no longer run it by calling it by name. `snakemake` needs to know the value for the wildcard, which is passed through the filename.